# Downloaded Selenium Webdriver Java zip, but it is missing the selenium JARs

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I downloaded the latest Selenium Webdriver zip file for Java and after I extracted it, I get a bunch of JAR files but missing the needed selenium-java-x.xx.x.jar file.

Selenium Client & WebDriver Language Bindings
http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/

Am I not extracting it correctly? I tried on both Mac and windows machine and I get these bunch of JARs instead.

[image]

Why do I not get the selenium JAR?

Comment: Have you tried to import `client-combined-3.0.1-nodeps.jar` ?

Comment: You have extracted correctly. Names of jars got changed.as Said by @FlorentB.`selenium-java-x.xx.x.jar` got changed to `client-combined-3.0.1-nodeps.jar`

Comment: 'client-combined-3.0.1-nodeps.jar' is outside the lib folder

Comment: Thanks. All the tutorials still says the old JAR name. @FlorentB, please post your answer and I can accept it as correct. I'm sure it would help some other guys.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Florent B. has commented, the old selenium-java-x.xx.x.jar was renamed to client-combined-x.x.x-nodeps.jar. The new name of the JAR was not very obvious.

Simply add this new JAR in your build path Libraries.

Comment: And it's stuff like this that makes me so thankful for Stack Overflow. You'd think Selenium devs would put a big announcement for that sort of thing right on the downloads page to tell the community this.

Answer (score 0):

Before changing or adding new `JARs`. Please check if Eclipse is taking the correct Java-SE version for execution. This can be verified while creating a new Java project. Select the latest Java-SE version installed on your machine from the drop-down list during project creation.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEmLI.png)